# i am getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out exception in IE 7 but not in IE 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, spring, internet-explorer-7

If i use IE7 to access my application & do some save or delete operations i am getting "java.net.ConnectException" but if i use IE 8, application is going smoothly. using of IE 7 is mandatory for the users i have no other go now.

Please guide me to solve the problem.

Quick answers would be deeply appreciated.

Thank You,
Pruthvi

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your application is trying to connect to. What operation is the application trying to do?

Can you post details of the exception?

How does the application behave under IE6, or FireFox or Chrome?

How does the application behave when you exercise the same behaviour without a browser (e.g. an integration test).

Are you using the same application instance when testing via the two different browsers?